# Why is WPF setting my data context to MS.Internal.NamedObject?

Tags: .net, wpf, datacontext

I have a program which crashes on .NET 4.0 / Windows 7, but works fine on .NET 4.5 / Windows 8+. When destroying a control (e.g. by closing the window in which the control lives), WPF appears to be trying to set `DataContext` to an object of type `MS.Internal.NamedObject` -- which fails because the control always expects the data context to be the view model that goes with that view:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'Foo.Bar.BazViewModel'.

What's going on here? Can I ask WPF to not mess with the data context like this, or should I otherwise disable the control when this happens?

Comment: `Can I ask WPF to not...` - No. You can't force WPF to your will. Correct whatever offending code you have. UI elements are not supposed to crash the whole application if their `DataContext` is set to whatever object, nor under any unexpected circumstance. Correct your code.

Comment: @HighCore: Nowhere is it documented that WPF reserves the right to change `DataContext` out from underneath a control.

Comment: Context...how exactly are you *destroying a control*?

Comment: @OmegaMan: The user closes the window in which the control lives.

Comment: @BillyONeal I am trying to eliminate situations...what happens if you destroy the control on a live window? Is it the window's data context or **just** the controls data context? Also what is the control in question. Can you provide a test snippet which illustrates the situation?

Comment: @BillyONeal you can keep trying to penetrate an iron wall with a wooden knife (and wondering why it isn't documented anywhere that the wood cannot break the iron), or you can correct the offending code. It should be a matter of `if (DataContext is MyViewModel)`... It's just the way things are. BTW, even if WPF didn't do that, you're creating a potential crash in your application, which is just bad. UI elements should "expect" a specific ViewModel, if you want, but they should never crash if a different ViewModel / DataContext is passed.

Comment: @BillyONeal Can you post me the external code stack trace?

Comment: What is the name of this `NamedObject`?  WPF uses this type for various sentinel values, and knowing the name can help narrow it down.

Comment: @HighCore: I strongly disagree. Code that tries to set DataContext to something else on this control is in error. Code that tries to trigger buggy behavior should crash.

Comment: @Mike: :sigh: Now I just need to get it to happen where I can get a debugger attached

Comment: @BillyONeal except you're crashing on an situation which is caused by WPF itself and you can't change S:

Comment: While investigating a problem relating to WPF binding including `{DisconnectedItem}` and also `Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type ...`I came across this which might be related to why you don't get the crash in .net 4.5 - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619658/wpf-virtualized-control-disconnecteditem-reference-when-datacontext-switch

Answer (score 1):

Something else is going on.

I recommend that a stand alone example is created which is representational of the structure, bindings and data distilled to its most base form. If the issue can be reproduced in the stand alone project, then you may have a bug which should be reported to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

More likely the example project will reveal the difference which is causing the situation which will allow you to fix the issue. Or at minimum post it to Stack Overflow and allow the answer sharks to feast on a fresh example kill; so to speak.

---

Async data operations may be coming in too late. Check for any *post* updates which could be signaled to be turned off.

Comment: I strongly suspect it is a bug of some sort which was fixed in .NET 4.5 and/or Win8.

Comment: @BillyONeal Was the program written on 4 then ported to 4.5 or visa versa?

Comment: Development is being done on a Win8 and/or 8.1 box, .NET 4.5, with the target platform set to .NET 4.0. Issue didn't appear until a customer tried running the app on a Win7 machine with .NET 4.0 (only) installed. Haven't run down whether or not the OS or the .NET version make the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue, but for what it's worth, I also experienced a strange where WPF would call my `DataContextChanged` handler for each view object in an `ItemsControl`. It occurred when I would remote-desktop into the server on which the app was running--yet I could not reproduce it on my machine or any other machine. Somehow I discovered the root cause: when the current Windows 7 theme is changed from Aero to Classic (or vice-versa), the `DataContext` of each object in the `ItemsControl` would get set to `MS.Internal.NamedObject` (but not destroyed). I temporarily side-stepped the problem by changing the colour scheme from Classic to Basic, which prevented that phenomenon from occurring upon RDP logon. For the case when my app is running and a user actually does change the theme, I modified my handler method to return if the `DataContext` is not of the expected type. However, even then, there are now doubles of all view items in the collection. Each time the theme changes, another complete set of instances is created (the latest instance of each "group" has the correct data context set by WPF; the rest are sort of orphaned)